# TCP push packet not delivered from tun

Tags: tcp, ip, iptables, tun, iproute

I setup simple packet intercept program, using two tuns, setup like this:

```
# ip tuntap add mode tun name tun0
# ip link set tun0 up
# ip addr add 10.0.0.0/31 dev tun0
# ip tuntap add mode tun name tun1
# ip link set tun1 up
# ip addr add 10.0.1.0/31 dev tun1
```

and redirect output to the program like this:

```
# ip rule add fwmark 1 table 1
# ip route add default dev tun0 table 1
# iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT --source 192.168.1.0 -o enp34s0 -p tcp --dport 9732 -j MARK --set-mark 1
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --source 10.0.1.1 -o enp34s0 -j MASQUERADE
```

I enabled `ip_forward` and disabled `rp_filter`. Packets received on `tun0` are processed, modified and ip/tcp checksums are updated.
I can even correctly intercept tcp handshake `SYN -> ACK,SYN -> ACK` part of communication, but after that, any incoming packet would be correctly intercepted modified and send out of tun, but it would never be delivered to local application.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found a problem, whilst I did recalculate the checksum, it only calculated correct one only for the TCP packets without any payload, thus TCP handshak get through and nothing else.